# Create multiple variable from foreach loop

Tags: php, variables

I have this script that gets weather data from a API.
But I need to have the temperatures of every day in seperate strings.
$day1Max, $day1Min, $day2Max, $day2Min, etc...

Is it possible to get these variables from a foreach loop?

```
<?php

$conditions_week = $forecast->getForecastWeek($latitude, $longitude);

echo "Forecast this week:\n";

foreach($conditions_week as $conditions) {
?>  
    
<tr>
<th><?php     echo $conditions->getTime('Y-m-d') . ': ' . $conditions->getMaxTemperature() . "\n"; ?></th>
<th><?php     echo $conditions->getTime('Y-m-d') . ': ' . $conditions->getMinTemperature() . "\n"; ?></th>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

This is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution :

```
<?php

class Conditions{
    function __construct($min,$max){
         $this->max = $max;
         $this->min = $min;
    }

    function getMaxTemperature(){
        return $this->max;
    }
    function getMinTemperature(){
        return $this->min;
    }
}

$conditions_week = array(new Conditions(5,10),new Conditions(-5,3));

echo "Forecast this week:\n";

foreach($conditions_week as $k=>$conditions) {
$varMin = "day".($k+1)."min";
$varMax = "day".($k+1)."max";
$$varMin = $conditions->getMinTemperature();
$$varMax = $conditions->getMaxTemperature();
?>  

<tr>
<th><?php     echo "Max : ". $conditions->getMaxTemperature() . "\n"; ?></th>
<th><?php     echo "Min : ". $conditions->getMinTemperature() . "\n"; ?></th>
</tr>
<?php

}


echo "day1min : " . $day1min;
echo '<br>';
echo "day1max : " . $day1max;
echo "<hr>";
echo "day2min : " . $day2min;
echo '<br>';
echo "day2max : " . $day2max;
```

You to generate your php variables $day1min, $day1max... inside the foreach and then you can use it outside the loop.

Here's the full example : https://3v4l.org/vX5bW

Comment: You're the proof that not all heroes wear capes!
Thank you sir, this works perfect!